# Redirect to android app if requirement are met

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am working on deeplink an android app but i want to be more specific, i only want to redirect to the app if certain conditions are met i.e if the user has already installed the app and has certain id then only the webpage should redirect the user to the app

Is their any way to expose the id stored in app to the webpage, so that it can read and decide whether to redirect to the app.

If that's not possible can the webpage start an service which runs in background check for the conditions and then redirect to the application

Are their any way by which the android app writes a data to a file and later it can be accessed from a webpage and then the webpage will decide whether to redirect or not

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing isn't possible — allowing random websites to pull data about apps on a user's phone would be a security/privacy risk.

However, you can probably get most the result via standard deep linking flows:

1. Attempt to launch the app from your webpage via a [URI scheme redirect](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-android-deep-linking-uri-schemes) or an [App Link](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-deep-linking-android-app-links).
2. If the app isn't installed, the URI scheme redirect link will simply do nothing. The App Link would fall back to the base url.

From your website, you can't easily determine if the user is logged into the app. This would require something like tying the UUID of every logged-in user within the app, sending that back to your server, and then comparing the UUID of every website visitor to that list. Probably not feasible.

Comment: i have implemented the deeplink flow but i want to prevent the redirect if requirements are not met with the user register on the app